# CATransform3DMakeRotation Setting AnchorPoint and position. iOS7 View position mistake

Tags: ios, objective-c, anchorpoint

CATransform3DMakeRotation Setting AnchorPoint and position
iOS7 View position mistake...
but iOS8 and iOS9 dont have this problem..
why?

---

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

[self setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 1) forView:self.chieldImageView];

}

-(void)setAnchorPoint:(CGPoint)anchorPoint forView:(UIView *)view
{

CGPoint newPoint = CGPointMake(view.bounds.size.width * anchorPoint.x,
                               view.bounds.size.height * anchorPoint.y);

CGPoint oldPoint = CGPointMake(view.bounds.size.width * view.layer.anchorPoint.x,
                               view.bounds.size.height * view.layer.anchorPoint.y);

newPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(newPoint, view.transform);
oldPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(oldPoint, view.transform);

CGPoint position = view.layer.position;

position.x -= oldPoint.x;
position.x += newPoint.x;

position.y -= oldPoint.y;
position.y += newPoint.y;

view.layer.position = position;
view.layer.anchorPoint = anchorPoint;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to the use of auto layout, on iOS8 and major they fixed it.
There are not so many solution, one is to keep the view you are transforming inside a container view. You use constraints on the container view to position it and in the contained (need to be transformed view) you just add it as a subview by keeping the `-translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to YES.
Check on Matt [book](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_autolayout_and_view_transforms).